# Linux bare system calls, not glibc

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I'm reading an article that explains how to call bare syscalls without passing through glibc. To call `chmod` and `exit`, use:

```c
#include <linux/unistd.h>
_syscall2(int,chmod,char*,f,int,m)
_syscall1(int,exit,int,r)
```

My `gcc` complains about them. What are their use, how do they work?

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0
$ gcc e.c 
e.c:2:15: error: unknown type name ‘setresuid’; did you mean ‘__NR_setresuid’?
 _syscall3(int,setresuid,int,r,int,e,int,s)
               ^~~~~~~~~
               __NR_setresuid
e.c:2:29: error: unknown type name ‘r’
 _syscall3(int,setresuid,int,r,int,e,int,s)
                             ^
e.c:2:35: error: unknown type name ‘e’
 _syscall3(int,setresuid,int,r,int,e,int,s)
                                   ^
e.c:2:41: error: unknown type name ‘s’
 _syscall3(int,setresuid,int,r,int,e,int,s)
                                         ^
```

Comment: `man 2 _syscall` says "*Starting around kernel 2.6.18, the `_syscall` macros were removed from header files supplied to user space.  Use syscall(2) instead.*" (2.6.18 was released in 2006.)

Comment: `man 2 _syscall`? Wow.

Comment: missing link to your article. That is a reason to downvote. And probably off-topic  here too, since without [MCVE]

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Looks like a MCVE to me: https://ideone.com/YkPkyA

Comment: An MCVE has a `main`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No, why? The question is about compilation errors. You don't need to link anything.

Comment: Alo, **why do you ask?** Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56414083/edit) your question to explain!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your article is probably obsolete.

If you code in C, there is no reason to avoid using the [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (notice the plural) as documented. Be also aware of the [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html). You could use some other [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) than the `glibc`  (e.g. [musl-libc](https://musl-libc.org/), [dietlibc](https://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/), etc...) and you might (but that is not recommended) statically link it.

You might use [syscall(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) (notice the singular) instead. I see no reason to do that, e.g. use [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) or [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) without `syscall`.

The [Assembly HowTo](http://asm.sourceforge.net/howto/Assembly-HOWTO.pdf) might be an interesting read (beware, it might be too 32 bits centric, most Linux PCs today are 64 bits x86-64).

See also [osdev.org](https://osdev.org/)

BTW, some old Unixes (e.g. Solaris) had a `libsys` providing *just* the syscalls, and their `libc` linked to it. I would like a `libsys` too! But on current Linux systems, it does not really matter, since almost every process (running some [dynamically linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable) is [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ing, after [ld-linux.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html), several segments and sections of your `libc.so.6`; for details, read Drepper's [*How to write a shared library*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) (since it also explains in details how shared libraries actually work). Use also [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) on some *running* process (e.g. `pmap $$` in a shell).

Some rare syscalls (e.g. [userfaultfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/userfaultfd.2.html) today 2Q2019) are not known by the `glibc`. They are an exception, because *most* [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) are wrapped by your libc (the wrapping usually just deals with [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) setting on failure). Be aware of [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html).

And you also should read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (it is a freely downloadable book, explaining the role of, and reason for, system calls)

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks. Any idea on why this is a bad post - i.e. downvoted?

Comment: @bicup It doesn't show a lot of research effort. Just a vague reference to "an article" (no name, no source) and no apparent attempt to read the documentation (which says that these macros have been removed since 2006).

Comment: I did my research. Do I have to explicitly say all the links I've clicked on which lead to nothing? I didn't know about that man page, hence why I was surprised it exists.

Comment: Yes, you do have to list the links you have read and followed. Hyperlinks can appear not only in answers (like I did above) but also in questions. The ethical rule is to spend more time in writing your question than the cumulated  time each of us takes to answer or just *read* it (because my time is as valuable as yours)

Comment: Will do next time. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @bicup I didn't know about that man page either. I just did a web search for `man _syscall2`.

Comment: @bicup - I think it would have been helpful if you provide a link to the article you referenced in *"I'm reading an article that explains..."*. I'm kind of surprised you got an answer without an upvote. Personally, I don't answer anything that cannot be upvoted. Otherwise, the question is junk and should not be answered; instead, it should be closed and deleted.

Comment: @jww I thought providing the full context and example would have been enough. I'll take into account all suggestions for my next questions.

Comment: How is this "And you also should read Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces (it is a freely downloadable book)" related?

Comment: It explains what *exactly* is a system call

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't asking about syscalls in general in my question, but those precise `_syscalln()` things. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Both are very related, and those `_syscall*`  things don't exist since probably the beginning of this century; and the very relevant question is **why do you ask?**

Comment: I don't understand you comment. All I'm saying is I was asking for what `_syscall*` are or were, not what syscalls are